# Python Matlab Engine in Docker

Tags: python, matlab, docker

I am developing a python application that calls on some matlab scripts using `eng = engine.start_matlab()`. This works fine on my local.

I am trying to deploy using Docker. When I try to build the image, the error is related to matlab not installed.

Is what I am trying to do possible? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what you did to install and verify Matlab in the docket container?
I think of docker containers as micro VMs, so if the application isn’t in the container it can’t be accessed by other apps in the container. Hope I got that concept right!

Answer (score 0):

U can try this images https://hub.docker.com/r/lz20061213/cfnet-matlab/tags
I can run it and start the engine